# trying to read XML value's with xsltproc

Tags: xml, bash, xslt

I'm want to read  from  but can't figure out how...

Here's the file:

```
<MBusData>

    <SlaveInformation>
        <Id>5000619</Id>
        <Manufacturer>SBC</Manufacturer>
        <Version>19</Version>
        <Medium>Electricity</Medium>
        <AccessNumber>254</AccessNumber>
        <Status>00</Status>
        <Signature>0000</Signature>
    </SlaveInformation>

    <DataRecord id="0">
        <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
        <Unit>Energy (10 Wh)</Unit>
        <Value>686648</Value>
    </DataRecord>

    <DataRecord id="1">
        <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
        <Unit>Energy (10 Wh)</Unit>
        <Value>686648</Value>
    </DataRecord>

<MBusData>
```

And here's the XSL Template that refuses to work:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Datarecord">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried to run it with:

```
xsltproc xslfile xmlfile
```

Hope you can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your XML input is not well formed: the last `<MBusData>` tag needs to be a **closing** tag `</MBusData>`.

Next, this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Datarecord">
```

selects nothing. You are in the context of the `/` root node, and there are no `Datarecord` elements that are children of `/`. Moreover, XML is case-sensitive and `Datarecord` is not the same thing as `DataRecord`. So you need to change this to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="MBusData/DataRecord">
```

Finally, `Value` is a **child** of `Datarecord`, not an **attribute** - so you need to change this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
```

---

### Edit:

> THX, it works, but what if I only want to read only one specific
>   DataRecord, lets say id="1"?

Then you should not use `for-each`. Instead, try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="MBusData/DataRecord[@id='1']/Value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: THX, it works, but what if I only want to read only one specific DataRecord, lets say id="1"?